# Unable to use reference to collection element in composite request

Tags: rest-api, composite

I'm unable to use reference to collection element in composite request. I get `References an invalid Datatype in composite request` error even though it's certainly String type.

My request

```
{
  "allOrNone": true,
  "compositeRequest": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Account",
      "referenceId": "RespList"
    },
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/@{RespList.objectDescribe.name}/describe",
      "referenceId": "Descr"
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Very interesting question, seems that `name` is not considered a string, but e.g. `label` is, so your query changed like so `/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/@{RespList.objectDescribe.label}/describe` does work for me

Comment: Also, and i know this might not help, this worked fine for me `"url": "@{RespList.objectDescribe.urls.describe}"`